# git cat-file: when was introduced the "--" escape parameter?

Tags: git

I noticed that in git version `1.8.3.1` (provided by CentOS 7) it seems this command is not working:

```
git cat-file -t -- "5378198ea7a83f5fa9bb3ba17f51be3a6ffbecc1:README.md"
```

(Obviously specify a correct git hash and an existing file at that revision)

This is the standard error:

```
usage: git cat-file (-t|-s|-e|-p|<type>|--textconv) <object>
   or: git cat-file (--batch|--batch-check) < <list_of_objects>

<type> can be one of: blob, tree, commit, tag
    -t                    show object type
    -s                    show object size
    -e                    exit with zero when there's no error
    -p                    pretty-print object's content
    --textconv            for blob objects, run textconv on object's content
    --batch               show info and content of objects fed from the standard input
    --batch-check         show info about objects fed from the standard input
```

To me, it seems that the problem is the "`--`" escape parameter that is interpreted as a type instead of an escape for consecutive arguments. In fact, this works to me:

```
git cat-file -t "5378198ea7a83f5fa9bb3ba17f51be3a6ffbecc1:README.md"
```

It exists with `0` with this result:

```
blob
```

So, in short.

### Question

How do you suggest to proceed to discover when the "`--`" parameter was introduced in git?

Related documents:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file (I don't see details)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750028/in-git-what-does-dash-dash-mean (no version/time details)
- https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1072 (not related to git itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git cat-file` used to have a strict check on the number of arguments to it, which meant that `--` couldn’t be used. The check happened before options were parsed, which is why you get the usage output immediately, with no indication of why the arguments are invalid.

This was [removed in May 2015](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b48158ac94cf725834b70b4a5ab7f2d152a741d4); the first release containing this change is 2.5.0.

To figure this out, I compared [`cat-file.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/cat-file.c) in version 1.8.3.1 to its current state; I noticed the check on argument versions, then looked for the commit which removed it.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I'm marking this as accepted solution. I think it could be useful to mention their changelog that clarify this and seems to confirm that this was changed in 2015: https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f9504c48ea59951a2aa3ee17e7c7fc36285e225/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt thank you so much

Comment: I thought of mentioning the changelog, but I couldn’t find anything that references this change explicitly; can you?

Comment: I only see this part in the changelog about that: «A heuristic we use to catch mistyped paths on the command line "git <cmd> <revs> <pathspec>" [<omissis>] must always be disambiguated with "--"» https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f9504c48ea59951a2aa3ee17e7c7fc36285e225/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt

Comment: Yes, but that doesn’t explain why `cat-file` suddenly started accepting `--`. It probably wasn’t noticed at the time, since the change was part of a code cleanup rather than an explicitly externally-visible change.